# Consolidate two node scripts into one & group clients into rooms

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have two separate node scripts which work individually (they are for dealing with realtime data feeds) I am trying to consolidate them into one script. Below is one complete script The other script is identical except it serves data for `MAP.room2` using a different database & spawn script.

I tried literally merging the 2 scripts together which worked (in so far as it didn't crash or anything) however once one client connected it requested all the data from both databases, and both spawned scripts, rather than just the data for the relevant room.

Having had a google it looks like `socket.emit('MAP.room1', newObj)` uses a room rather than a namespace. What I cant understand from the examples is what I need to do with the section where I do `io.sockets.on` what I need to change so only the relevant data is served up to the relevant client. The client looks like it sends an `emit "join"` requesting the correct data.

```
var app = require('http').createServer(handler),
        io = require('socket.io').listen(app),
        fs = require('fs');
var cp = require('child_process');
var tail = cp.spawn('/var/www/html/test/test/room1-db.rb');

app.listen(8000);

function handler(req, res) {
        fs.readFile('/var/www/html/test/updates/test.html', function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.writeHead(500);
        return res.end('Error loading webpage');
        }
            res.writeHead(200);
            res.end(data);
        });
}

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
       console.log();

    //Read from mongodb//
    var connection_string = '127.0.0.1:27017/room1-web';
    var mongojs = require('mongojs');
    var db = mongojs(connection_string, ['items']);
    var ls = db.collection('items');
    db.items.find({}, {'_id': 0, "data.time":0}).forEach(function(err, doc) {
        if (err) throw err;
        if (doc) { socket.emit('MAP.room1', doc); }
});

// Get updates from ruby script //
        tail.stdout.on('data', function(chunk) {
        var closer = chunk.toString()

        var sampArray = closer.split('\n');
        for (var i = 0; i < sampArray.length; i++) {
        try {
                var newObj = JSON.parse(sampArray[i]);

// DO SOCKET //
socket.emit('MAP.room1', newObj);
} catch (err) {
}}  
});});
```

The client side web page connects with the following; '+t' is defined elsewhere, in my example cases it would be room1 and room2

```
function startDiagram(t, e) {
    var n = io.connect(e);
    n.on("connecting", function () {
    n.emit("join", t), $("#room-map").fadeTo(0, 1)
    }), n.on("MAP." + t, function (t) {
        logMessage(t), updateMapElement(t)
    })
}
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction of what I need to change to get this working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after understanding how the call-back from the client side works I was able to literally merge the scripts & use an `if` statement based on what the client sent back.

```
socket.on('join', function(mapname) {
\\ do socket stuff here\\ }

if (mapname == 'room1') {
\\the read correct room from db\\ }

if (mapname == 'room2') {
\\the read correct room from db\\ }
```

It's a dirty hack & I need to completely re-understand how socket/node work to get something a bit more practicable together but this moved me along a step.